# function variable does not live outside a for loop

Tags: julia

I have a generic function in julia that the aim is to say if a member of a vector of
a given dimension is negative or not. After a few variations I have:

```
function any(vec)
    dim = size(vec)
    for i in 1:dim[2]
        fflag = vec[1,i] < 0 
        println("Inside any, fflag = ", fflag)
        if fflag == true
            result = 0
            println("blabla ", result)
            break
        else
            result =1
            println("blabla ", result)
            continue
        end
    end
    println("hey, what is result? ")
    println(result)
    return result
end
```

If I run a test I found the following result:

```
Inside any, fflag = false
blabla 1
Inside any, fflag = false
blabla 1
Inside any, fflag = false
blabla 1
hey, what is result? 

result not defined
at In[7]:57
```

I don't know why the compiler says me that 'result' is not defined. I know the variable exist but why does not live outside the for loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation on variable scoping](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/manual/variables-and-scoping/) clearly states that a for loop defines a new scope. This means `result` is going out of scope when execution leaves the for loop. Hence it is undefined when you call `println(result)`

Defining `result` in advance of the for loop should give the behaviour you are expecting:

```
function any(vec)
    dim = size(vec)
    result = -1
    for i in 1:dim[2]
       ...
```

Or if you do not wish to assign a default value, and are sure the for loop will set its value, you can do:

```
function any(vec)
    dim = size(vec)
    local result
    for i in 1:dim[2]
       ...
```

In the first example, if the for loop does not set a value, `result` will be `-1`.

In the the second example, not setting a value in the for loop will leave `result` undefined.

Comment: You can also just do `local result` beforehand without assignment.

Comment: StefanKarpinsk could you please explain what you mean in more detail? I've been using the answer above but I'd like to stop having to assign a specific value to the initial definition outside the for loop.

Comment: @user3061923 I've added some more detail to my answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a similar thing to this that can be used within general code instead of within a function definition ?